# JSON callback after file upload

Tags: ajax, json, upload

I have problem trying to upload a file via json/ajax and does not look like the file was uploaded.  Only name of the file was displayed in the console output.

My html code as shown below.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upIFrame"> 

<input type="file" id="uploadFileName" name="uploadFileName" size="30" >&nbsp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<input type="button" id="upgradeFile" name="upgradeFile" value="Upload" onclick="ul.load()" />
<iframe id="upIFrame" name="upIFrame" src="#" style="display: none;"></iframe>
</form>
```

the ul.load() is calling this line below and eventually the transfer.ajax code will call

```
transfer.ajax({
               url:'upload.cgi', 
               data:{filename: ul.filename}, 
               success: success, 
               error: error, 
               async: true 
});
```

ul.filename comes from uploadFileName

and transfer.ajax code shown below

```
transfer = {
ajax: function(p) {        
if (p.url.indexOf('/') == -1) {
  p.url = '/cgi-bin/' + p.url;
}
p.type = 'POST';
p.contentType = 'application/json';  
p.dataType = 'json';
p.cache = false;

if (p.data != undefined) {
    p.data = JSON.stringify(p.data);
}

$.ajax(p);
}
};
```

the result after viewing in Fire Fox is 
JSON

```
filename   "file.tgz"
```

Source

```
{"filename":"file.tgz"}
```

Could some tell me what I did wrong or what I missed?

TIA

I modified the code to the following...

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("filename",ul.filename);
$.ajax({
  url: "/cgi-bin/test.cgi",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  beforeSend : function(xhr){                           
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name=\"uploadFileName\"; filename=\"' + ul.filename + '\"');
},
```

});

and the Request Headers in Fire Fox are as

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Disposition form-data; name="uploadFileName"; filename="test.tgz"
Content-Length  157
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------20025277823050
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

but the "Post" display the following

Source
-----------------------------20025277823050 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

test.tgz -----------------------------20025277823050--

How would I include filename="test.tgz"? what's missing?

TIA

Comment: nothing particular.  Just a call to the CGI to handle the file upload and return whether it is successful or not

Comment: Well you just uploaded the filename, to upload an actual file you'll have to use something like [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: do I still need to add the xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition'...) for the onbeforesend function?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking but I'm going to go ahead and say no.

Comment: I modified my code to the following...

Comment: Remove the  `Content-Disposition` header, what is ul? Use something like `fd.append("uploadFileName",document.getElementById('uploadFileName').files[0]);`

Comment: Thank-You it work, but it appears formdata is not supported by IE.  Is there an alternative solution that will support IE as well?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("filename",ul.filename);`enter code here`
$.ajax({
  url: "/cgi-bin/test.cgi",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  
  contentType: false,   
  beforeSend : function(xhr){                           
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name=\"' + ul.filename + '\"; filename=\"' + ul.filename + '\"');
}
});
```

I think name attribute should be as the file name.
Thanks :).